# OS X Terminal wildcard doesn't work for some paths

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, ls

Okay, this is weird, hopefully someone here can explain what is happening.

I am using OS X 10.9.4 and I want to list files in a directory (and filter them using *)

I want to look for zip files in the Downloads directories of my user directory and my son's directory.

This shows all files including ones ending in .zip: `sudo ls /Users/Jamie/Downloads/` 
But when I try to filter it: `sudo ls /Users/Jamie/Downloads/*zip` 
I get `No such file or directory`

But that same command works fine in my directory!? `sudo ls /Users/Hamish/Downloads/*zip`

In fact even this generates the `No such file or directory` error on his path but not mine: `sudo ls /Users/Jamie/Downloads/*`

Comment: And *are* there files in `/Users/Jamie/Downloads` (other than `.` files)?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of files there including zip files (visible when I don't use the wildcard)

Comment: I'm guessing the expansion of the asterisk is happening before the sudo, so it expands to the files with your credentials. It doesn't make too much sense to me, might be a bug. I can't test it right now. You can always do this workaround `sudo ls /Users/Jamie/Downloads/ | grep -E 'zip$'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pathname expansion occurs at the time you run the command, so be expanded before running sudo.

You can instance a new shell inside sudo with: `sudo sh -c "ls /Users/Jamie/Downloads/*.mp3"`

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `grep` to filter your results.  So

```
$ sudo ls -l /Users/other/Library/Keychains/*keychain
ls: /Users/other/Library/Keychains/*keychain: No such file or directory
```

will fail but using `grep` will work

```
 sudo ls -l /Users/other/Library/Keychains|grep .keychain
 -rw-r--r--   1 other staff    48K Jan 31 18:27 login.keychain
```

Additionally, `grep` allows you to search for multiple items with the `-e` option.

```
 $ sudo ls -laRh /Users/other/Library/Logs|grep -e Finder -e Google
  -rw-r--r--   1 other  staff    18K Jan 31 18:27 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.log
  -rw-------   1 other  staff    56K Jan 31 18:27 .Finder_2014-06-25-165714.crash.plist
  -rw-------@  1 other  staff    52K Jan 31 18:27 Finder_2014-06-25-165714.crash
```

Hope this helps.